# Error in NVL function, How to change fallowing sql query available in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm using in **MYSQL** , I created sql query like

**SELECT C.ID, C.name, C.addr, C.DOB, C.phone, C.username,
nvl((SELECT 'Librarian'
FROM Librarian L
WHERE L.ID = C.ID), 'Customer') AS role
FROM Customer C
WHERE C.username = '' AND C.password = '';**

, but the above query does not work, it gives Error message "Error Code: 1305. FUNCTION final_clz_db.**nvl** does not exist 0.000 sec ",. , Please help me to clarify the error,...

Answer (score 3):

NVL() is an Oracle function, not MySQL, which is what that error message is telling you.

ifnull(column, "replacement value") is the MySQL equivalent.

Comment: You save my skin! Thank you @jaketclarke

Comment: Love it when something from 8 years ago helps out! @AlexandreBarbosa